How do I attach this piece of my desk drawer back into the silver items so that i can use my desk normally like before?
A few weeks ago the desk drawers broke off my desk and I'm looking to see how I can put them back together. The photos are of the main piece I need to reattach so that I can proceed with putting a desk drawer and the keyboard drawer back in place.
Do I need specific tools to repair this? I haven't reached out to a store like Home Depot or anything yet.



Agreed. This question has all the detail needed for an answer and has a well up- voted  answer intact.

@Robthechamp24, if you look at the side of the piece of wood you're holding in the lower picture, you will either see the silver-colored metal cam piece that Kelsham is discussing below, or there may be a plastic cover piece you need to pry off that is hiding the cam. You should be able to see the metal cam showing down inside the edge hole in the picture.

What you're showing is cam-lock fasteners, common on flatpack hardware. There are two metal pieces, the posts seen in your photo and a cam cylinder that fits in the hole in the other piece and is rotated to grab and lock onto the post. You need both. If the cam has been lost, you can buy replacement sets and steal the cams from those.

Agreed - looks like it was not put together properly in the first place and the cam-locks have come loose.
